# Laravel - add new data into result

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, eloquent

I have this function to get all max-offers from maxoffers table:

```
public function maxoffers($id)
{    
    $offers = Maxoffer::where('article_id', $id)->latest()->get(['id', 'price', 'start', 'user_id']);    
    return $offers;
}
```

and I get this:

```
 [{"id":121,"price":67,"start":"Sat, 23 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":114,"price":45,"start":"Sun, 08 May 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":9},{"id":113,"price":53,"start":"Sun, 24 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":111,"price":55,"start":"Wed, 01 Jun 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":11},{"id":110,"price":53,"start":"Fri, 03 Jun 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":107,"price":53,"start":"Wed, 03 Aug 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":106,"price":53,"start":"Mon, 01 Aug 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":105,"price":53,"start":"Tue, 16 Aug 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":104,"price":55,"start":"Thu, 21 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":11},{"id":101,"price":57,"start":"Wed, 17 Aug 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8}]
```

Now I have also:

```
$start = 'Sun, 03 Apr 2016 00:00:00';
$end = 'Sat, 23 Sep 2016 00:00:01';
```

I need to go through `$maxoffers` from `$start` date to `$end` date day by day. If there is no date for that day, I need to add a new object into `$maxoffers` with the following data:

```
 {"title":,"price":100,"start":"DATE_WHICH_NOT_EXCIST INTO_OFFERS","user_id":8}
```

So how I can go through `$maxoffers` and if there is not some date in period from `$start` to `$end` then to add new data to result?

**UPDATE:**

I try:

```
public function maxoffers($id)
    {

        $start_date = ;
        $end_date = ;

        $offers = Maxoffer::where('article_id', $id)
                            ->where('start', '>=', $start_date)
                            ->where('start', '<=', $end_date)
                            ->get(['id', 'price', 'start', 'user_id']);

        $start_date = 'Sun, 03 Apr 2016 00:00:00';

        $end_date = 'Sat, 23 Sep 2016 00:00:00';

        while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {

            $start_date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));

            $count = 0;

            foreach($offers as $offer) {
                if(strtotime($offer->start) == strtotime($start_date)) {
                    $count++;
                }
            }

            if($count == 0) {
                Maxoffer::create(['title' => null, 'price' => '100', 'start' => $start_date, 'user_id' => 8 ]);   
            }

        }

        // do some code to update $offers variable before you return it

        return $offers;
    }
```

but give me this error:
[image]

Comment: In your `MaxOffer` model it seems you are using Carbon in a Mutator for `start` date but the `Carbon::createFromFormat()` fails in there.

Comment: @MariosFakiolas is right. You could change your `$start_date` format in your `while` loop to match your `setStartAttribute` method (`'m/d/Y h:i a'`).

Comment: I change to: $start_date = '04/01/2016 12:00 am';

        $end_date = '09/10/2016 12:00 am'; but again is the same errors

Comment: also in MaxOffer model I have: public function setStartAttribute($date){
        $this->attributes['start']= Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i a', $date);
    }
    public function getStartAttribute($date){
        return (new Carbon($date))->format('m/d/Y h:i a');
    }

Comment: Did you change the first line inside the while loop to `$start_date = date ("m/d/Y h:i a", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));`?

Comment: I have now: QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testiranje`.`maxoffers`, CONSTRAINT `maxoffers_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `maxoffers` (`price`, `start`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (100, 2016-04-04 00:00:00, 2016-04-22 09:03:42, 2016-04-22 09:03:42)) BUT I DONT WANT TO ADD INTO DATABASE... I JUST WANT TO GET THIS AS OUTPUT TO SEND AS JSON TO FRONTEND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ver simple. YOu just need to use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison) for date manipulation.

```
 $offers  = []; //for example I am using an empty array

$start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('Sun, 03 Apr 2016 00:00:00');
$end_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('Sat, 23 Sep 2016 00:00:00');


while(!$start_date->eq($end_date))
{
   $flag = true;

   foreach ($offers as $offer)
   {
     if ($offer['start'] == $start_date->toRfc2822String())
     {
        $flag = false;
        break;
     }
   }

    if($flag)
    {
      $temp = [];
      $temp['title'] = "Title ";
      $temp['price'] = "100";
      $temp['start'] = $start_date->toDateString();
      $temp['user_id'] = 8;

      array_push($offers,$temp);
    }
    $start_date->addDay();
}
```

Here Just Pass the valid format of date for `$start_date` and `$end_date`. In your case it is valid so no problem there. Now use `eq()` method for date comparison and add one day for every iteration. I used `$temp` as an example. You can define this array's values and keys as you want. Since you are not using `collection` you need to iterate to each element in array to see if that date exists or not.

Comment: I retrun $offers but I get only: [{"id":138,"price":130,"start":"05\/02\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8},{"id":137,"price":130,"start":"06\/28\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8},{"id":136,"price":138,"start":"05\/07\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8},{"id":135,"price":135,"start":"05\/06\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8},{"id":134,"price":157,"start":"05\/05\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8},{"id":133,"price":132,"start":"05\/04\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8},{"id":132,"price":131,"start":"05\/03\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8}]

Comment: Make sure in your `$end_date`  variable you set your time to "00:00:00" not "00:00:01".

Comment: no, I use your exmple... and I think that will be better if we convert date to miliseconds and after that to days t get integer who will be indipendent from hours,minutes change ...

Comment: As you have a `carbon` object there will be many ways to manipulate dates.

Comment: but yes, I use collection, offers ... ->get()

Comment: also isn't be better if I when create auction add all that dates so there is no need to make loop and while... so I will save server resource

Comment: Why would you add those extra records which won't be useful to you. Your table will contain many unnecessary rows so it is better you create those record at runtime and very minor resources will be used to create these records.

Comment: as I say, this code wont work for me but why dont work? return me only [{"id":138,"price":130,"start":"05\/02\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8},{"id":137,"price":130,"start":"06\/28\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8},{"id":136,"price":138,"start":"05\/07\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8},{"id":135,"price":135,"start":"05\/06\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8},{"id":134,"price":157,"start":"05\/05\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8},{"id":133,"price":132,"start":"05\/04\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8},{"id":132,"price":131,"start":"05\/03\/2016 12:00 am","user_id":8}] - which variable I need to return?

Comment: @Andrew Sry for late reply. If you copied my code there was a mistake done by me. `If` statment containes `;` at the end and because of that you are not the desired result. Just remove the `;` and it will work.

Comment: But now I get: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: @Andrew Because you are using `get()` which will give you collection but  you mush have an array. So just add `toArray()` at the end to convert the collection to Array.

Comment: no I just make: $offers->push($temp) ... thans for help, but just one more question... becouse I will add maxoffers just once when auction is created and get maxoffers at every new user session is't be better to have all maxoffers into database and then just get it... maxoffer never will be more than 50 empty rows... also what you think about idea to sell that process frontend?

Comment: why would you add unnecessary data to database? It is better to generate these kind of extra data at runtime. Backend would be good to generate these kind of data. As per my view Frontend should not generate anything new. It should only use the data sent by the server. It can represent that in differate way but should not manipulate or add anything new.

Comment: please represent that in your - different way

Comment: Above code is perfect. It is generating results dynamically at the backend.

Comment: Either you make a common date format or try to make a `OR` condition to check all the possibility.